# Where GID didSignInFor has actually signed in user?

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I'm trying to save user picture to Firebase Storage, retrieve it's `downloadUrl`and save it all to `CoreData`. I call the uploading function and in it's it's completion I call the `CoreData`saving function. I have it all working except for one little detail: if I call it from `GID didSignInFor` user doesn't have permission to write to `storage`yet because is not signed in so it fails. I have tried calling the functions where I do perform the segue , thinking that there the sign in process would have been completed and I had permission to write to `Storage`but it doesn't see `user`. So I tried to call it at the very end but have the same result of not having permission yet. Can you spot where I'm doing wrong with the `didSignInFor`? You can see my tries by the commented out code. Many thanks as always.
Here is the method:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        // ...
        print("User successfully signed in with Google",user)
        guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken else {return}
        guard let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken else {return}
        let credentials = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credentials) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to create user with Google account", error)
                return
            } else {

                // here user in not accessible yet

                print("Succesfully created new user in Firebase with Google account")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "continueSegue", sender: self)
            }
        }
        // user details
        UserDetails.shopId = user.userID
        UserDetails.fullName = user.profile.name
        UserDetails.givenName = user.profile.givenName
        UserDetails.familyName = user.profile.familyName
        UserDetails.email = user.profile.email

        if user.profile.hasImage {
//            UserDetails.logoUrl = String(describing: user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 100)) // String // wrong.. use the downloadUrl from Firabase Storage
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 100))

            if let imageData = data {
                UserDetails.logo = UIImage(data: imageData)


//                // Post image to Firebase Storage here it fails at first sign in because of storage rules
//                Firebase.uploadImage(completed: { (true) in
//                    // Save user to CoreData
//                    User.saveUserDetails(shopId: UserDetails.shopId!, name: UserDetails.fullName!, address: UserDetails.address ?? "", phoneNumber: UserDetails.phoneNumber ?? "", latitude: UserDetails.latitude ?? "", longitute: UserDetails.longitude ?? "", logo: UserDetails.logo!, logoUrl: UserDetails.logoUrl!)
//                }, UserDetails.logo!)


            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do the uploading in `viewWillAppear` of the following vc. It now works as wanted.